# Adding a class to the active slide in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I basically want the centre image in the slider to be twice as big as the others. I need to be able to pass the class active to the centre image and remove it from the last image. So that the centre image is always twice as big. Is it possible to do this with my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // function active_class(){
  //   $(".active").next().addClass('active');
  //   $(".img_cont").index(1).addClass('jiji');
  // }
  // active_class();
  
  
  var slide_count = $(".carousel li").length;
  var slide_width = $(".carousel li").width();
  var slide_height = $(".carousel li").height();
  var total_width = slide_width * slide_count;
  
  $(".cont").css({ height: slide_height, width: slide_width, paddingLeft: slide_width , paddingRight: slide_width });
  $(".carousel").css({ width: total_width, marginLeft: - slide_width});
  $(".carousel li:last-child").prependTo(".carousel");
  $("#next").css("right", slide_width);
  $("#prev").css("left", slide_width);
  
  function next_slide(){
    $(".carousel").animate({
      left: + slide_width
    }, 400, function(){
      $(".carousel li:last-child").prependTo(".carousel");
      $('.carousel').css('left', 0);
    }
    );
  }
  
  function prev_slide(){
    $(".carousel").animate({
      left: - slide_width
    }, 400, function(){
      $(".carousel li:first-child").appendTo(".carousel");
      $(".carousel").css("left", 0);
    }
    );
  }
  
  $("#next").click(function(){
    next_slide();
  });
  $("#prev").click(function(){
    prev_slide();
  });
  
  var interval_time = 4000; // 1s
  var mouse_hover_flag = false;
  
  $(".cont").hover(function(){
    mouse_hover_flag = true;            
  }, function () {
    mouse_hover_flag = false;
  });

  setInterval(function() {
      if (!mouse_hover_flag) {//if not true
          next_slide();
      }
  }, interval_time);
  
});
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cont{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;/*removes white space*/
  margin: 60px auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 600px;
}

.carousel li{
  float: left;
  width: 750px;
  height: 350px;
}

.carousel li img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#next{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  right: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#prev{
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img_cont{
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.active{
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div id="next">
  </div> 
  <div id="prev">
  </div> 
  <ul class="carousel">
    <li class="img_cont active">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-2.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="img_cont">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-1500-700-3.jpg" alt="" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/pen/OgQLjE

Comment: Which image is in the center? I see an image on the left and one on the right https://codepen.io/Reece_Dev/full/OgQLjE/

Comment: Th bigger image is the centre one it may not appear so as I am yet to make it responsive so that the bigger image stays centred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to remove active class from all `li` elements, select the first and add the class again.

For example:

```js
  function next_slide(){
    $(".carousel").animate({
      left: + slide_width
    }, 400, function(){
      $(".carousel li:last-child").prependTo(".carousel");
      $('.carousel').css('left', 0);

      // Add the following line to prev_slide too:
      $('.carousel li').removeClass('active').eq(0).addClass('active');
    }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Awesome had to change 0 to 1 as its not the very left image that I wanted to change but the one after. So just so that were clear you remove the class from all the li then add it to the li with the index of 0?

Comment: Correct. If your active element should be the 2nd `li` select it by call eq(1) on your jQuery selection.